# How to do sorting base on field of document?

Tags: mongodb

Let's say i have a lot of data with this pattern in mongoDB:

```
db.customer.find()

{'_id':ObjectId('someId'),'customer':'brendon','address':'singapore','activity':[{'id':someId,'detail':'approaching'},{'id':someId,'detail':'explaining'},{'id':someId,'detail':'deal'}]}
```

this data means i have customer collection and each customer has array of activity,

now, for all customer i want to do paging/sorting the activity about 10 activity per page base on customer/document.
and
how to do this in mongoDB.

in relational sql this is represented with:

```
customer (custId, name, address)
activity (actId, detail, custId)

select * from activity
left join customer
limit 10,0
```

Comment: You can use the [`$slice`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/slice/) projection operator, but an array field that's big enough to require paged access and sorting should probably be in a separate collection.

Comment: @JohnnyHK i think i need comparing to use getnext() method and calculate the count of first read data to meet the count of the destination data.